# Get those terms with a specific meta key value

Tags: terms

I'm having a custom taxonomy for addresses. And I've created a true/false button through acf plugin to tell an address that it's the standard address.

How can I get only the one term that has "standard address" set to "true"?

Here is my approach:

```
    $taxonomy = 'addresses';
    $args = array(
       'numberposts'    => 1,
       'meta_query' => array(
          array(
            'key'     => 'standardaddress',
            'value'   => true,
            'compare' => '=',
            ),
        ),
        'suppress_filters' => false,
    );
    $terms = get_terms( $taxonomy, $args );
```

But this way I only get the first term entered, which doesn't have "standardaddress" set to "TRUE".

Comment: Currently, taxonomies terms have not meta fields. They will have in WordPress 4.4. If it is something implemented by ACF you should ask to their support team. Or are you usgin WordPress 4.4?. By the way, you seem to be using WP_Query aguments and not the arguments accepted by [`get_terms()` function](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_terms).

Comment: Unfortunately ACF doesn't seem to support it, too. So I have to wait until December for WP 4.4

Comment: Maybe you can tell me how to do this with WP 4.4?

Comment: This is now indeed part of the WP core and using meta_query in your get_terms query is the right way to retrieve them. Providing that they are saved using the WP term API, not ACF.